# Div slider in reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the link of an example of divslider: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/ykbgT/light/

But in this example the divs are moving from right to left

but i want to move the divs from left to right now.. this website already has an editor inside it.
so please help me move the divs in reverse direction. because on my code i want to go both sides

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '50%',
            }, 500 );
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-150%',
            }, 500 );
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me on your JS Fiddle:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
           $(this).animate({
                left: '50%',
            }, 500 );
        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
            $(this).css({
                'left': '-150%',
            } );
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '150%',
            }, 500 );
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Brain, but I tried your code it is not working. the link that I have posted in the question that website has an editor where you can go and check. But still thanks for trying, and if possible please try and let me know the correct code.

Comment: Dude I need one more small favor can you make the div's scroll automatically as well.. I mean when i dont click dey shud scroll automatically as well like a slideshow but when I click on them they shud slide as they are alredy..

Comment: $('.box').ready(function() {
 var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
    {    
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).css("left", "150%");
        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '50%',
            }, 500 );
        } else {
            $(this).animate({
                left: '-150%',
            }, 500 );
        }
    });
},4000);
});​I tried to append this code along wid the one you sent yesterday but this one creates problem sometimes i dunno whats wrong

Comment: What you would do is simple: setTimout(function(){}($('.box').click();),5000}; '5000' is for a five second delay. Please upvote if you have a chance. :)

Comment: Look at the code above ur comment.. Thats what I did. But it is creating a small problem. Sometimes the div's are overlapping for e.g. when I press left scroll and 5 sec interval automatically triggers the scroll the div's overlap. do u want me to send the whole code.. Gimme ur e-mail ID.

Comment: I want to upvote but i dont even hav a 15 points to do that!!

Comment: Could you create a new question? post the problematic code with a jsfiddle, and post the link here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192524/overlapping-slides-in-jquery-divs-get-overlapped

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left: 150%; /* changed this */
}
#box3 {
    background-color: red;
    left: -150%; /* changed this */
}
​
```

and

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
            $(this).css("left", "-150%");
        } else if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
            $(this).animate({left:'50%'},500);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({left:'150%'},500);
        }
    });
});​
```