# Overlapping slides in jquery, divs get overlapped

Tags: jquery

the first block here is for the automatic sliding of the divs after every 5 secs

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                    var refreshId = setInterval( function() 
                    {    
                        $('.box').each(function() {
                            if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                                $(this).css("left", "150%");
                            } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
                                $(this).animate({
                                    left: '50%'
                                }, 500 );
                            } else {
                                $(this).animate({
                                    left: '-150%'
                                }, 500 );
                            }
                        });
                    },5000);

 //the second block is to move the div's to left on clicking the leftbutton               

         $(".leftbutton").click(function(){
                    $('.box').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                            $(this).css("left", "150%");
                        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
                            $(this).animate({
                                left: '50%'
                            }, 500 );
                        } else {
                            $(this).animate({
                                left: '-150%'
                            }, 500 );
                        }
                    });
                });
the third block is to move the div's to right side on click of right button



               $(".rightbutton").click(function(){
                    $('.box').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                            $(this).animate({
                                left: '50%'
                            }, 500 );
                        } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
                            $(this).css({
                                'left': '-150%'
                            } );
                        } else {
                            $(this).animate({
                                left: '150%'
                            }, 500 );
                        }
                    });
                });
            });


//the below is the HTML

<div id="container">

        <div id="box1" class="box">Div #1</div>
        <div id="box2" class="box">Div #2</div>
        <div id="box3" class="box">Div #3</div>

    </div>

// the below is the CSS



 body {
        padding: 0px;    
    }

    #container {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;  
    }

    .box {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 300px;
        line-height: 300px;
        font-size: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px solid black;
        left: 50%;
        top: 100px;
        margin-left: -25%;
    }

    #box1 {
        background-color: green;
        left: -150%;
    }

    #box2 {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    #box3 {
        background-color: red;
        left: 150%;
    }
```

so basically after a few trials and errors the divs 1,2 & 3 are overlapping and only one div is visible. I guess you will have to try the code a few times before getting to the problem.
        ​

Comment: Could you make sure to jsFiddle this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9FPBA/2/           okie this is the link where you can see the code and i have roughly made two buttons for left and right animation. hope i was able to do wat u asked for.

Comment: Hi there Brian, is the link that I posted working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var refreshId;
    var restartAnimation = function() {
        clearInterval(refreshId);
        refreshId = setInterval( function() 
        {    
            $('.box').each(function() {
                if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                    $(this).css("left", "150%");
                } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
                    $(this).animate({
                        left: '50%'
                    }, 500 );
                } else {
                    $(this).animate({
                        left: '-150%'
                    }, 500 );
                }
            });
        },1000);
    }

    restartAnimation()

    $(".leftbutton").click(function(){
        restartAnimation();
        $('.box').each(function() {
            if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                $(this).css("left", "150%");
            } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: '50%'
                }, 500 );
            } else {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: '-150%'
                }, 500 );
            }
        });
    });
    $(".rightbutton").click(function(){
        restartAnimation();
        $('.box').each(function() {
            if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: '50%'
                }, 500 );
            } else if ($(this).offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
                $(this).css({
                    'left': '-150%'
                } );
            } else {
                $(this).animate({
                    left: '150%'
                }, 500 );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

// The above javascript solved the problem completely now the occurence of both manual and automatic animation at the same time has been avoided by calling a function that resets the automatic animation. This doesn't let the div's to get overlapped. This is not something that I came up with. I got help from someone else. but still I wanted to share the answer for someone who could encounter a similar issue.